# Jquery - Autocomplete from database?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, autocomplete

I have a text input that I would like to auto complete. Users will use this input categorize items stored in a database. I would like it to suggest existing categories based on user input.

However there could be a very large number of categories as the application grows. I'd like to base the suggestions on what has been typed so far AND the popularity of the selection?

What is a good way to handle this? Thank you!

Comment: did you considered limiting number suggestions to 10 items?  

is the simplest method and avoid of showing user list of one hundred items

Comment: Sure, that could work. Is it possible to base it on what has been typed so far AND the popularity of the selection?

Comment: you can use javascript to read what was typed into text field, pass it thought ajax to serwer, there make a query based on typed string (here you can add any mechanisms to make some suggestions more popular) then return result to ajax and display on screen.  Take a look http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/